# Calling a function after a 'visible' rule has been applied

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is the context: I've a div whose visibility is linked to an observable boolean with `data-bind="visible: theBoolean"`.

When the boolean switches to `true`, the div gets visible and that's when I need to trigger an action (which is refreshing a CodeMirror object, because CodeMirror doesn't render correctly when it's initialized in an area that is not displayed).

I haven't found a way to call a function after the effect of a binding has completed. I could obviously use `setTimeout`, but I hope there is a better way to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knockout `template` binding has support of `afterRender` callback (and many other callbacks). http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

You may want to wrap your view in a template in order to access `afterRender` callback.

In fact, knockout `foreach` binding internally uses `template` binding to support those callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The additional trick was to control the visibility with 'if' instead of 'visible', so the 'afterRender' event is fired each time the template gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [explicitly subscribe to the observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables):

```
myViewModel.theBoolean.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue){ // (Or `newValue === true`, to check if it's not just truthy)
        // The boolean changed to `true`! Do something here.
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do that, the code executed here would fire before the div gets visible. I need to execute code after the effect of the observable (which is, setting the div visible) has completed.

Comment: Then I'd suggest putting it in a short timeout.

Comment: Yes that is the option I mentioned using setTimeout. Thanks for your contribution!